# Read Text File of integers into One 2D matrix in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, text, matrix

I Matlab I want to read a File of the following format :
1 23 6 547 8 9 .....
56 56 85 2 7 9 ....

I want to read this file and store it in a 2D array that has the same shape as the file. Reading in Matlab seems complicated as it has conversions ratios! and other stuff

Any Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the function `importdata`

```
importdata('test.txt')

ans =

     1     2
     3     4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use load (assuming a text file named 'a'):

```
load a
```